# $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{5\cdot5^x+3^x-4^x}{5^x +2^x+27\cdot9^x}$

Tags: calculus, limits, taylor-expansion

How can I solve this limit.  (Here $x$ belongs to natural numbers $\Bbb{N}$.) 
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty} \dfrac{5\cdot5^x+3^x-4^x}{5^x +2^x+27\cdot9^x}$$

My try:  I tried using L'Hospital, expansions of all terms using Taylor's series, and did work out.  I was just thinking if there is any simpler method?

Comment: Hint: Divide top and bottom by $9^x$.

Comment: U mean to say that generally i should divide the numerator and denominator by the largest term of all.

Comment: Generally. In this case it will work very nicely.

Comment: Yup it worked out.Thanks

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dividing by $9^x$ will give you the limit value

Answer (score 2):

Since Andre already gave one way, let's see how the squeeze theorem works here:

$$ 0\le\frac{5\cdot5^x+3^x-4^x}{5^x +2^x+27\cdot9^x}\le\frac{5\cdot5^x+3^x}{27\cdot 9^x}=\frac5{27}\left(\frac59\right)^x+\frac1{27}\left(\frac13\right)^x\xrightarrow[x\to\infty]{}0+0=0$$

Answer (score 1):

Of course asymptotics yields the most elegant way

since $a^x \pm b^x \sim_\infty a^x$ if $a > b > 0$

we have that the limit is equivalent to

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{5\cdot 5^x}{27 \cdot 9^x} = \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{5}{27}\cdot \left(\frac{5}{9}\right)^x = 0$$